# error , Symbol 'vector' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I am using eclipse in linux to develop a c++ application and  I am getting this editor annotation error  "Symbol 'vector' could not be resolved" from the following code lines

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer;
```

I feel that some library is missing or the paths are not set. I explicitly downloaded STL but its of no use. Do I have to re install GCC on my linux ?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you 'explicitly downloaded STL', that shouldn't be necessary and perhaps you made some mistake at that point.

Comment: If the paths are not set you should get an error on `#include <vector>`. What's the *first* error in your output?

Comment: Did you try using gcc or cc outside of eclipse just to link a Hello World c++ file including vector? I would give that a shot.

Answer (score 21):

In Eclipse, right-click on the project name...Select Index...Rebuild.

Comment: FYI - not the same as a refresh (I thought it was).

Comment: I think this probably hits a lot of users who are new to Eclipse. This helped me with my first imported project in Eclipse, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the STL vector definition in your program. Put:

```
#include <vector>
```

at the top of your file and it should work.

Comment: i have included this at the top but of no use

Comment: Err.. if you're going to downvote a post, at least have the decency to explain why...

Comment: And again.. this post is a year old now.. the answer is perfectly reasonable, and without any further response from the OP, there's not really much I can do to improve it. So if you're going to downvote, I'd love to know why?!?

Comment: @StevieG your answer maybe right if there is an _compilation_ error. But op states that he is getting a **annotation** error. It is an specific problem to eclipse as it uses an different code scanner for the annotation task. I have a similar problem like op and my code is compiling and linking fine but eclipse still messes up the standard template library.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I believe the problem arises from how std:: autocompletion is updated. Eclipse should be getting this from the Path and Symbols, but it could be buggy. I had to clean all Eclipse settings after upgrading gcc (thus, g++), since you're in Linux it's under your home folder ~/.eclipse/.

Thus,

1) Re-started Eclipse after cleaning ~/.eclipse/.

2) checked that Path and Symbols (under right-click on project > General > Path and Symbols) included all the upgraded gcc and c++ include directories (vector should be under ./gcc/version/include/c++/version/)

3) Rebuild index.

4) Created a *.cpp file that includes the *.h where the error is showing. This will force Eclipse to backtrace dependencies for *.h.

5) Rebuild index and/or restart a few times as required, now I can see vector at the end of std:: autocompletion.

[image](see picture)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think that this answer is correct. The question is related to this other solved post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803685/eclipse-cdt-symbol-cout-could-not-be-resolved . I solved the problem with a similar procedure to the one explained by @wgodoy (using the mentioned post).

Answer (score 2):

See Also related question: [Eclipse CDT: Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803685/eclipse-cdt-symbol-cout-could-not-be-resolved)

for me the problem was that in `#include <vector>` somewhere there is `#include <bits/c++config>` which has a different include path than `#include <vector>`

i.e.: `/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<vector>
```

should be included at top.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>
```

Also, std::vector is template type, so you have to use it like

```
std::vector<char> buffer;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I feel that some library is missing or the paths are not set.

Yes, this sounds like a linker error. Linkers deal with symbols.

> I explicitly downloaded STL but its of no use.

Hopefully you mean libstdc++, GNU's implementation of the C++ Standard Library, and you probably shouldn't have done this. Your toolchain comes with the proper stdlib implementation.

> Do I have to re install GCC on my linux?

Probably wise. And let this installation handle the standard library.

Also, on the off-chance that you're playing with your compilation command line, remember to invoke `g++` *not* `gcc`; `g++` automatically links in the C++ runtimes and stdlib implementation, whereas `gcc` is designed for C.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently vector belongs to C++ standard template library from MinGW perspective. so in addition to

```
 #include <vector>
```

Add

```
using namespace std;
```

after the header file inclusions.

Answer (score 0):

Created a `*.cpp` file that includes the `*.h` where the error is showing. This will force Eclipse to backtrace dependencies for `*.h`.
Is working for me...

Answer (score 0):

I know that this problem was already solved, but it still appears as the top result on Google.

Using **Eclipse Neon** for **Linux** I solved it with ***`Quick Fix`***:

- right click at "vector" in the editor,
- then "Quick Fix"

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have some system-specific include directories missing in your settings which makes it impossible for indexer to correctly parse iostream, thus the errors. Selecting `Index -> Search` For Unresolved Includes in the context menu of the project will give you the list of unresolved includes which you can search in `/usr/include` and add containing directories to C++ Include Paths and Symbols in Project Properties.

On my system I had to add `/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu` for `bits/c++config.h` to be resolved and a few more directories.

Don't forget to rebuild the index (Index -> Rebuild) after adding include directories.

Answer (score -1):

adding **#include< vector >** and **using namespace std;** solved my problem